# K8s Ingress, initiate ingress controller nginx error?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have two spring boot container, I want to setup ingress service. As document [here](https://medium.com/@cashisclay/kubernetes-ingress-82aa960f658e) says, ingress has two parts, one is controller, the other is resources.

My two resources are two containers: gearbox-rack-eureka-server and gearbox-rack-config-server. The difference is port so that ingress could route traffic by different ports. My yaml files are listed below:

eureka_pod.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: gearbox-rack-eureka-server
  labels:
    app: gearbox-rack-eureka-server
    purpose: platform_eureka_demo
spec:
  containers:
  - name:  gearbox-rack-eureka-server
    image: 192.168.1.229:5000/gearboxrack/gearbox-rack-eureka-server
    ports:
        - containerPort: 8761
```

eureka_svc.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: gearbox-rack-eureka-server
  labels:
    name: gearbox_rack_eureka_server
spec:
  selector:
    app: gearbox-rack-eureka-server
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 8761
      nodePort: 31501
      name: tcp
```

config_pod.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: gearbox-rack-config-server
  labels:
    app: gearbox-rack-config-server
    purpose: platform-demo
spec:
  containers:
  - name:  gearbox-rack-config-server
    image: 192.168.1.229:5000/gearboxrack/gearbox-rack-config-server
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8888
    env:
      - name: EUREKA_SERVER
        value: http://172.16.100.83:8761
```

config_svc.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: gearbox-rack-config-server
  labels:
    name: gearbox-rack-config-server
spec:
  selector:
    app: gearbox-rack-config-server
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 8888
      nodePort: 31502
      name: tcp
```

My ingress-nginx controller is mostly copied [from the link above](https://medium.com/@cashisclay/kubernetes-ingress-82aa960f658e),

ingress_nginx_ctl.yaml:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: ingress-nginx
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: http
  - name: https
    port: 443
    targetPort: https
---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ingress-nginx
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      containers:
      - image: nginx:1.13.12
        name: ingress-nginx
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
          - name: http
            containerPort: 80
            protocol: TCP
          - name: https
            containerPort: 443
            protocol: TCP
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 10254
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        env:
          - name: POD_NAME
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.name
          - name: POD_NAMESPACE
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        args:
        - /nginx-ingress-controller
        - --default-backend-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-default-backend
```

I did following commands, they are successful.

```
kubectl apply -f eureka_pod.yaml
kubectl apply -f eureka_svc.yaml
kubectl apply -f config_pod.yaml
kubectl apply -f config_svc.yaml
```

Then I got error from execute `kubectl apply -f ingress_nginx_ctl.yaml`, the pod does not start, logs are listed below:

```
[root@master3 nginx-ingress-controller]# kubectl get pods
NAME                             READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
gearbox-rack-config-server       1/1       Running            0          39m
gearbox-rack-eureka-server       1/1       Running            0          40m
ingress-nginx-686c9975d5-7d464   0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   6          7m
[root@master3 nginx-ingress-controller]# kubectl logs -f ingress-nginx-686c9975d5-7d464
container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"/nginx-ingress-controller\": stat /nginx-ingress-controller: no such file or directory"
```

I created a directory /nginx-ingress-controller under root, and repeat the steps again, it still said same error. Does someone could point me the problem?

I put my ingress_nginx_res.yaml as follows for reference, it may have errors also.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: 172.16.100.83
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: gearbox-rack-eureka-server
          servicePort: 8761
  - host: 172.16.100.83
    http:
      paths:
      - path:
        backend:
          serviceName: gearbox-rack-config-server
          servicePort: 8888
```

==========================================

## second   edition

After change image link, The previous errors disappear, but still it has following permission problem:

```
[root@master3 ingress]# kubectl get pods
NAME                             READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
gearbox-rack-config-server       1/1       Running            0          15m
gearbox-rack-eureka-server       1/1       Running            0          15m
ingress-nginx-8679f9c8ff-5sxw7   0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   5          12m
```

The log message is as follows:

```
[root@master3 kube]# kubectl logs ingress-nginx-8679f9c8ff-5sxw7
W0530 07:54:22.290114       5 client_config.go:533] Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.
I0530 07:54:22.290374       5 main.go:158] Creating API client for https://10.96.0.1:443
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NGINX Ingress controller
  Release:    0.15.0
  Build:      git-df61bd7
  Repository: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
I0530 07:54:22.298248       5 main.go:202] Running in Kubernetes Cluster version v1.9 (v1.9.2) - git (clean) commit 5fa2db2bd46ac79e5e00a4e6ed24191080aa463b - platform linux/amd64
F0530 07:54:22.298610       5 main.go:80] ✖ It seems the cluster it is running with Authorization enabled (like RBAC) and there is no permissions for the ingress controller. Please check the configuration
```

It is RBAC problem. I check the install script which is downloaded from forum:

heapster-rbac.yaml:

```
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: heapster
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: system:heapster
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: heapster
  namespace: kube-system
```

One of related kubelet start argument is as follows: (I do not know whether it is relevant).

```
Environment="KUBELET_AUTHZ_ARGS=--authorization-mode=Webhook --client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt"
```

By which way, I could grant permission to ingress controller? Just put namespace kube-system to ingress_nginx_ctl.yaml?

================================================================

## Third edition

I put Kun Li's codes into `ingress_nginx_role_rb.yaml`, and run the following commands:

```
kubectl apply -f eureka_pod.yaml
kubectl apply -f eureka_svc.yaml
kubectl apply -f config_pod.yaml
kubectl apply -f config_svc.yaml
kubectl apply -f ingress_nginx_role_rb.yaml (just copy paste from Kun Li's answer)
kubectl apply -f nginx_default_backend.yaml
kubectl apply -f ingress_nginx_ctl.yaml
```

nginx_default_backend.yaml file is listed below:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nginx-default-backend
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: http
  selector:
    app: nginx-default-backend
---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: nginx-default-backend
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-default-backend
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      containers:
      - name: default-http-backend
        image: chenliujin/defaultbackend
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 8080
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 10m
            memory: 20Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 10m
            memory: 20Mi
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP
```

ingress_nginx_ctl.yaml is listed below:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: ingress-nginx
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: http
  - name: https
    port: 443
    targetPort: https
---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ingress-nginx
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      serviceAccount: lb
      containers:
      - image: quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.15.0
        name: ingress-nginx
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
          - name: http
            containerPort: 80
            protocol: TCP
          - name: https
            containerPort: 443
            protocol: TCP
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 10254
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        env:
          - name: POD_NAME
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.name
          - name: POD_NAMESPACE
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        args:
        - /nginx-ingress-controller
        - --default-backend-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-default-backend
```

From here, we could see service ingress-nginx namespace is default, not kube-system. But anyway, controller is up.

```
[root@master3 ingress]# kubectl get pods -n kube-system
NAME                                      READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
calico-etcd-cdn8z                         1/1       Running   0          11m
calico-kube-controllers-d554689d5-tzdq5   1/1       Running   0          11m
calico-node-dz4d6                         2/2       Running   1          11m
coredns-65dcdb4cf-h62bh                   1/1       Running   0          11m
etcd-master3                              1/1       Running   0          10m
heapster-5c448886d-swp58                  1/1       Running   0          11m
ingress-nginx-6ccc799fbc-hq2rm            1/1       Running   0          9m
kube-apiserver-master3                    1/1       Running   0          10m
```

ingress-nginx pod's namespace is kube-system (shown above), but its service's namespace is default.(shown below).

```
[root@master3 ingress]# kubectl get service
NAME                         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
gearbox-rack-config-server   NodePort       10.97.211.136   <none>        8888:31502/TCP               43m
gearbox-rack-eureka-server   NodePort       10.106.69.13    <none>        8761:31501/TCP               43m
ingress-nginx                LoadBalancer   10.105.114.64   <pending>     80:30646/TCP,443:31332/TCP   42m
kubernetes                   ClusterIP      10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP                      44m
```

as mentioned in the comments, expert's response help me to move forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ingress-controller, image quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.15.0 should be used. And you need setup nginx-default-backend pod and service.

About RBAC, I think you need a seviceaccount to deploy your nginx-ingress-controller, with the following roles and bindings:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: lb
  namespace: kube-system

---

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-normal
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - configmaps
      - endpoints
      - nodes
      - pods
      - secrets
    verbs:
      - list
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - nodes
    verbs:
      - get
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - services
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - "extensions"
    resources:
      - ingresses
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
        - events
    verbs:
        - create
        - patch
  - apiGroups:
      - "extensions"
    resources:
      - ingresses/status
    verbs:
      - update

---

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-minimal
  namespace: kube-system
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - configmaps
      - pods
      - secrets
      - namespaces
    verbs:
      - get
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - configmaps
    resourceNames:
      - "ingress-controller-leader-dev"
      - "ingress-controller-leader-prod"
    verbs:
      - get
      - update
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - configmaps
    verbs:
      - create
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - endpoints
    verbs:
      - get

---

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-minimal
  namespace: kube-system
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: nginx-ingress-minimal
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: lb
    namespace: kube-system

---

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-normal
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: nginx-ingress-normal
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: lb
    namespace: kube-system
```

Comment: the image you point to give me the right direction. I also have nginx-default-backend. Please see my current problem about RBAC in question second edition.

Comment: The answer is the right direction after I read several RBAC documents. But I still could not make pod ingress-nigix up, please see my third edition in the question.

Comment: Put 'serviceAccount: lb' under 'spec:' in your controller yaml.

Comment: Exactly. I still have trouble in ingress_nginx_res.yaml file. But so far, for controller it is correct. I open another question. I will put link here also. At the same time, I override/update edition three to have correct yaml files.

Comment: Related link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33808912/can-you-route-an-kubernetes-ingress-resource-based-on-port