# Kubernetes, Ingress resource configuration, route to same host, but different ports

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

This question is relevant to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50582016/k8s-ingress-initiate-ingress-controller-nginx-error). From [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33808912/can-you-route-an-kubernetes-ingress-resource-based-on-port), I could say using ingress to route to different ports service is feasible.

I first listed two of my services: (eureka and config), the `ingress_nginx_res.yaml` is as belows:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host:
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: gearbox-rack-eureka-server
          servicePort: 8761
  - host:
    http:
      paths:
      - path:
        backend:
          serviceName: gearbox-rack-config-server
          servicePort: 8888
```

as one could see, gearbox-rack-eureka-server is listening port 8761, and gearbox-rack-config-server is listening port 8888.

Right now, all service and k8s is installed on my local virtual box(centos 7x), 172.16.100.83, after `kubectl apply -f ingress_nginx_res.yaml`, i could see it is up.

```
[root@master3 ingress]# kubectl get ing
NAME         HOSTS     ADDRESS   PORTS     AGE
my-ingress   *                   80        11s
```

I try verify ingress, then I put `172.16.100.83:8761`, it say could not visit this website. So I believe there is something wrong with my configuration. I put all related configuration and steps as below:

**eureka_pod.yaml:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: gearbox-rack-eureka-server
  labels:
    app: gearbox-rack-eureka-server
    purpose: platform_eureka_demo
spec:
  containers:
  - name:  gearbox-rack-eureka-server
    image: 192.168.1.229:5000/gearboxrack/gearbox-rack-eureka-server
    ports:
        - containerPort: 8761
```

**eureka_svc.yaml:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: gearbox-rack-eureka-server
  labels:
    name: gearbox_rack_eureka_server
spec:
  selector:
    app: gearbox-rack-eureka-server
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 8761
      nodePort: 31501
      name: tcp
```

**config_pod.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: gearbox-rack-config-server
  labels:
    app: gearbox-rack-config-server
    purpose: platform-demo
spec:
  containers:
  - name:  gearbox-rack-config-server
    image: 192.168.1.229:5000/gearboxrack/gearbox-rack-config-server
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8888
    env:
      - name: EUREKA_SERVER
        value: http://172.16.100.83:8761
```

**config_svc.yaml:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: gearbox-rack-config-server
  labels:
    name: gearbox-rack-config-server
spec:
  selector:
    app: gearbox-rack-config-server
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 8888
      nodePort: 31502
      name: tcp
```

**ingress_nginx_role_rb.yaml:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: lb
  namespace: kube-system

---

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-normal
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - configmaps
      - endpoints
      - nodes
      - pods
      - secrets
    verbs:
      - list
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - nodes
    verbs:
      - get
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - services
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - "extensions"
    resources:
      - ingresses
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
        - events
    verbs:
        - create
        - patch
  - apiGroups:
      - "extensions"
    resources:
      - ingresses/status
    verbs:
      - update

---

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-minimal
  namespace: kube-system
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - configmaps
      - pods
      - secrets
      - namespaces
    verbs:
      - get
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - configmaps
    resourceNames:
      - "ingress-controller-leader-dev"
      - "ingress-controller-leader-prod"
    verbs:
      - get
      - update
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - configmaps
    verbs:
      - create
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - endpoints
    verbs:
      - get

---

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-minimal
  namespace: kube-system
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: nginx-ingress-minimal
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: lb
    namespace: kube-system
---

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-normal
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: nginx-ingress-normal
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: lb
    namespace: kube-system
```

**nginx_default-backend.yaml**

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nginx-default-backend
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: http
  selector:
    app: nginx-default-backend
---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: nginx-default-backend
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-default-backend
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      containers:
      - name: default-http-backend
        image: chenliujin/defaultbackend
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 8080
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 10m
            memory: 20Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 10m
            memory: 20Mi
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP
```

**ingress_nginx_ctl.yaml**

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: ingress-nginx
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: http
  - name: https
    port: 443
    targetPort: https
---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ingress-nginx
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      serviceAccount: lb
      containers:
      - image: quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.15.0
        name: ingress-nginx
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
          - name: http
            containerPort: 80
            protocol: TCP
          - name: https
            containerPort: 443
            protocol: TCP
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 10254
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        env:
          - name: POD_NAME
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.name
          - name: POD_NAMESPACE
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        args:
        - /nginx-ingress-controller
        - --default-backend-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-default-backend
```

Anything wrong with my configuration? Or any hints on trouble shooting command so that I could manage by myself?

=====================================================

## second edition

1.
I have my virtual machine centOs(7.x) running in my host machine win10, professional edition. I donot use google cloud or AWS. I do not have any load balancer, I suppose nginx is reverse proxy, so it has load balancer function. 
Does image in `ingress_nginx_ctl.yaml`: `quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.15.0` is a connector between ingress and nginx, and it is not nginx itself?

2
a) I edit /etc/hosts, and I put following two entries：

```
  172.16.100.83 gearbox-rack-eureka-server.sup.com
  172.16.100.83 gearbox-rack-config-server.sup.com
```

b) I see there is dns server in k8s cluster, how to add these two entries into dns? or where is dns console so that I could put these two entries?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your environment, are you sure you have 'loadbalancer' ? To simplify, you can just use 'hostNetwork: true' to setup your nginx-controller-deploy, so you can access the controller through host ip directly.

And, since we access all kinds of service through ingress-controller, how we differentiate different service? Using domain name. We can point gearbox-rack-eureka-server.your.domain to gearbox-rack-eureka-server:8761, while use gearbox-rack-config-server.your.domain point to gearbox-rack-config-server:8888 in ingress, like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: gearbox-rack-eureka-server.your.domain
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: gearbox-rack-eureka-server
          servicePort: 8761
  - host: gearbox-rack-config-server.your.domain
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: gearbox-rack-config-server
          servicePort: 8888
```

And config domainname to your host ip, then use domainname to access these service.

Comment: 1. Isn't ingress_nginx_ctl.yaml has nginx image (quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.15.0) ?  Nginx is inverse proxy so I take it as load balancer.

Comment: 2. How to config domainname to my host ip which is 172.16.100.83, editing /etc/hosts, add 172.16.100.83 www.supwisdom.com?

Comment: About 1, 'type: LoadBalancer' has special means in service definition, it always work together with GCP, aws ..., which have externalloadbalancer provied, refer to [loadbalancer usage](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#type-loadbalancer).  About 2, yes, you can config domainname through /etc/hosts, or config it at your domain name server.

Comment: 1. I have one centos(7.x) virtual machine, host machine is win10. And I do not use any cloud provider service. Do I have to pull nginx image to be load balancer?

Comment: 2. Please see edition two in my question, since I could not format text in comments.

Comment: for q1, yes, ingress-controller is a connector between ingress and nginx. Controller get pods info through watch ingress, servcie, endpoints resources to update the nginx.conf file, then call nginx to handle loadbalancing.   for q2, put domain name into /etc/hosts, and config domainname in the ingress_nginx_res.yaml, then use domainname to access your service, that's all.

Comment: which nginx image I shall download/use from hub.docker.com? In my case, how to configure nginx.conf?

Comment: nginx has been included in the nginx-ingress-controller image, and nginx.conf is maintained by controller, don't need to be configured manually.

Comment: I configured eureka_svc.yaml and config_svc.yaml as clusterIP. What's more, I made other modification. This question is invalid now. I will have a new question. The link would put here.

Comment: My related question is at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50691266/kubernetes-configuration-ingress-ingress-nginx-service-external-ip-pending

Answer (score 0):

I have found several problems here:

1. In terms of Kubernetes, when you specify `type: LoadBalancer` for Service, it relies on external load balancer provided by a cloud provider. So if you have no such load balancer in your cluster, you cannot use `type: LoadBalancer` in your settings for ingress-nginx service. But still you have to share your ingress to the outer world, and the easiest way to do it is to use `type: NodePort`. For example:

   ```
   kind: Service
   apiVersion: v1
   metadata:
     name: ingress-nginx
   spec:
     type: NodePort
     selector:
       app: ingress-nginx
     ports:
       - port: 80
         nodePort: 31080
         name: http
   ```

   Now you can reach Ingress by using address `http://<ip-address-of-any-node>:31080`. For example, `http://172.16.100.83:31080`
2. Next step, you need to provide configuration for Ingress. You can imagine Ingress abstraction as configuration for Ingress-controller (configuration for Nginx in your case).

   ```
   apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
   kind: Ingress
   metadata:
     name: my-ingress
   spec:
     rules:
     - http:
         paths:
         - path: /eureka
           backend:
             serviceName: gearbox-rack-eureka-server 
             servicePort: 8761 
         - path: /config
           backend:
             serviceName: gearbox-rack-config-server 
             servicePort: 8888
   ```

   As you mentioned, here Nginx as Ingress-controller plays role of a reverse proxy and matches Paths in `http://<ip-address-of-any-node>:31080/<path>` with Services and Ports.
3. Also, it is incorrect to use `type: NodePort` for services you expose with Ingress. It is better to use `type: ClusterIP`. So, for your services:

   ```
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: Service
   metadata:
     name: gearbox-rack-eureka-server
     labels:
       name: gearbox_rack_eureka_server
   spec:
     selector:
       app: gearbox-rack-eureka-server
     type: ClusterIP
     ports:
       - port: 8761
         name: tcp
   ---
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: Service
   metadata:
     name: gearbox-rack-config-server
     labels:
       name: gearbox-rack-config-server
   spec:
     selector:
       app: gearbox-rack-config-server
     type: ClusterIP
     ports:
       - port: 8888
         name: tcp
   ```

   Now you can reach eureka on `http://172.16.100.83:31080/eureka` and config on `http://172.16.100.83:31080/config`