# kubernetes configuration Ingress，ingress_nginx service external IP pending

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have a virtual machine centos(ver 7.4) on win10 machine, I do not use AWS, Google cloud service, nor Azure. I put master and node in one machine. My original problem domain have 5 components, I configure them as ClusterIP, so they could communicate with each other(eureka, config,api,uaa,zipkin). Now I only need api talk outside. But for short, I make two components for convenience (api and eureka). But now, api needs to receive from outside of cluster. So that I configure ingress. When ingress, I need to configure rbac. I put my yaml file here with error message.

eureka_pod.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: gearbox-rack-eureka-server
  labels:
    app: gearbox-rack-eureka-server
    purpose: platform_eureka_demo
spec:
  containers:
  - name:  gearbox-rack-eureka-server
    image: 192.168.1.229:5000/gearboxrack/gearbox-rack-eureka-server
    ports:
        - containerPort: 8761
```

eureka_svc.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: gearbox-rack-eureka-server
  labels:
    name: gearbox_rack_eureka_server
spec:
  selector:
    app: gearbox-rack-eureka-server
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 8761
      name: tcp
```

api_pod.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: gearbox-rack-api-gateway
  labels:
    app: gearbox-rack-api-gateway
    purpose: platform-demo
spec:
  containers:
  - name:  gearbox-rack-api-gateway
    image: 192.168.1.229:5000/gearboxrack/gearbox-rack-api-gateway
    ports:
    - containerPort: 5555
    env:
      - name: EUREKA_SERVER
        value: http://gearbox-rack-eureka-server:8761
      - name: CONFIG_SERVER
        value: http://gearbox-rack-config-server:8888
      - name: CONFIG_PROFILE
        value: docker
      - name: CONFIG_LABEL
        value: master
      - name: ZIPKIN_SERVER
        value: http://gearbox-rack-zipkin-server:9411
```

api_svc.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: gearbox-rack-api-gateway
  labels:
    name: gearbox-rack-api-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    app: gearbox-rack-api-gateway
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 5555
      name: tcp
```

ingress_nginx_role_rb.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: lb
  namespace: kube-system

---

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-normal
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - configmaps
      - endpoints
      - nodes
      - pods
      - secrets
    verbs:
      - list
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - nodes
    verbs:
      - get
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - services
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - "extensions"
    resources:
      - ingresses
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
        - events
    verbs:
        - create
        - patch
  - apiGroups:
      - "extensions"
    resources:
      - ingresses/status
    verbs:
      - update

---

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-minimal
  namespace: kube-system
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - configmaps
      - pods
      - secrets
      - namespaces
    verbs:
      - get
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - configmaps
    resourceNames:
      - "ingress-controller-leader-dev"
      - "ingress-controller-leader-prod"
    verbs:
      - get
      - update
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - configmaps
    verbs:
      - create
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - endpoints
    verbs:
      - get

---

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-minimal
  namespace: kube-system
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: nginx-ingress-minimal
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: lb
    namespace: kube-system

---

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-normal
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: nginx-ingress-normal
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: lb
    namespace: kube-system
```

nginx_default_backend.yaml:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nginx-default-backend
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: http
  selector:
    app: nginx-default-backend
---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: nginx-default-backend
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-default-backend
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      containers:
      - name: default-http-backend
        image: chenliujin/defaultbackend
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 8080
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 10m
            memory: 20Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 10m
            memory: 20Mi
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP
```

ingress_nginx_ctl.yaml:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: ingress-nginx
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    nodePort: 31080
---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ingress-nginx
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      serviceAccount: lb
      containers:
      - image: quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.15.0
        name: ingress-nginx
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
          - name: http
            containerPort: 80
            protocol: TCP
          - name: https
            containerPort: 443
            protocol: TCP
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 10254
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        env:
          - name: POD_NAME
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.name
          - name: POD_NAMESPACE
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        args:
        - /nginx-ingress-controller
        - --default-backend-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-default-backend
```

ingress_nginx_res.yaml:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
spec:
  rules:
   - host:
     http:
       paths:
       - path: /eureka
         backend:
           serviceName: gearbox-rack-eureka-server
           servicePort: 8761
   - host:
     http:
       paths:
       - path: /
         backend:
           serviceName: gearbox-rack-api-gateway
           servicePort: 5555
```

when I try `172.16.100.88:31080/uaa/login`, (my virtual machine current IP is `172.16.100.88`) it says following connection problme:

```
[centos@master ~]$ sudo curl http://172.16.100.88:31080/uaa/login
curl: (7) Failed connect to 172.16.100.88:31080; Connection refused
```

I check ingress-nginx pod, it seems request has not yet reached nginx.

```
[centos@master ~]$ sudo kubectl logs ingress-nginx-5c6d78668c-c78rd -n kube-system
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NGINX Ingress controller
  Release:    0.15.0
  Build:      git-df61bd7
  Repository: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
W0606 03:24:39.256706       7 client_config.go:533] Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.
I0606 03:24:39.257090       7 main.go:158] Creating API client for https://10.96.0.1:443
I0606 03:24:39.269897       7 main.go:202] Running in Kubernetes Cluster version v1.10 (v1.10.3) - git (clean) commit 2bba0127d85d5a46ab4b778548be28623b32d0b0 - platform linux/amd64
I0606 03:24:39.271426       7 main.go:84] validated kube-system/nginx-default-backend as the default backend
I0606 03:24:39.403474       7 stat_collector.go:77] starting new nginx stats collector for Ingress controller running in namespace  (class nginx)
I0606 03:24:39.403505       7 stat_collector.go:78] collector extracting information from port 18080
I0606 03:24:39.415000       7 nginx.go:278] starting Ingress controller
I0606 03:24:40.518572       7 event.go:218] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"default", Name:"my-ingress", UID:"041fb77f-6939-11e8-971e-fa163e39f742", APIVersion:"extensions", ResourceVersion:"1040", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'CREATE' Ingress default/my-ingress
I0606 03:24:40.615398       7 nginx.go:299] starting NGINX process...
I0606 03:24:40.615582       7 leaderelection.go:175] attempting to acquire leader lease  kube-system/ingress-controller-leader-nginx...
I0606 03:24:40.618811       7 controller.go:168] backend reload required
I0606 03:24:40.618835       7 stat_collector.go:34] changing prometheus collector from  to default
I0606 03:24:40.623350       7 leaderelection.go:184] successfully acquired lease kube-system/ingress-controller-leader-nginx
I0606 03:24:40.623400       7 status.go:196] new leader elected: ingress-nginx-5c6d78668c-c78rd
I0606 03:24:40.744438       7 controller.go:177] ingress backend successfully reloaded...
I0606 03:25:40.635267       7 status.go:361] updating Ingress default/my-ingress status to [{ }]
I0606 03:25:40.640390       7 event.go:218] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"default", Name:"my-ingress", UID:"041fb77f-6939-11e8-971e-fa163e39f742", APIVersion:"extensions", ResourceVersion:"1185", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'UPDATE' Ingress default/my-ingress
```

When I login in to pod gearbox-rack-api-gateway, I could see clearly it redirects to the page I expected. so there must be some configuration wrong in my yaml files.

```
[root@master8g ingress]# kubectl exec -it gearbox-rack-api-gateway -- /bin/bash
root@gearbox-rack-api-gateway:/# curl http://localhost:5555/uaa/login
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8]> <html lang="en" class="ie8 no-js"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]> <html lang="en" class="ie9 no-js"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<!--<![endif]-->
<!-- BEGIN HEAD -->
<head>

  ....
</head>
<!-- END HEAD -->

<body>

  <div class="blank"></div>

 ...
  </div>

  <script>
    document.getElementById("username").focus();
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

=================================================================

## second edition

In my virtual machine, I type `telnet localhost 31080`, rejected. but `telnet -6 localhost 31080` succeed. And `netstat -anp | less` find 31080 binding kube-proxy. I put `sysctl -q -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1` and `sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1` in my starting script, but got same result.

```
tcp6       0      0 :::31080                :::*                    LISTEN      7436/kube-proxy
```

==============================================================

## Third edition

Yesterday question about Ipv6 is stupid. I misconfigured /etc/hosts. Now I have telnet localhost 31080 work, but when I do curl http://localhost:31080/uaa/login, it hangs there for long time. So pod is listening. When I issue the command curl http://localhost:31080/uaa/login, at the same time, I check several pods' log. Log has shown no error and has no log to say the port 31080 has been sent request. I checked ingress-nginx pod logs: I paste some here.

```
I0608 07:15:31.436658       5 leaderelection.go:184] successfully acquired lease kube-system/ingress-controller-leader-nginx
I0608 07:15:31.436683       5 status.go:196] new leader elected: ingress-nginx-6ccc799fbc-tl588
I0608 07:15:31.493595       5 controller.go:177] ingress backend successfully reloaded...
I0608 07:16:31.441317       5 status.go:361] updating Ingress default/my-ingress status to [{ }]
I0608 07:16:31.444803       5 event.go:218] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"default", Name:"my-ingress", UID:"b96b555d-6aeb-11e8-acff-080027709399", APIVersion:"extensions", ResourceVersion:"1270", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'UPDATE' Ingress default/my-ingress

[root@master8g ingress]# curl http://localhost:31080/uaa/login
^C
[root@master8g ingress]# telnet localhost 31080
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
^C^CTerminated
```

My own wild guess is that ingress nginx pod's namespace is kube-system, nginx service's name space is default, my-ingress's namespace is default. nginx-default-backend's name space is kube-system. Whether cross namespace traffic is forbidden.

[image]

Experts what kind of logs do you need?

=======================================================

## Forth Edition

After define all ingress controller, ingress resources as default namespace, now I did get move further. Now nginx redirect my `http request to https:` request. How to disable this feature will make my ingress working wholly.

```
[root@master8g ingress]# curl http://172.16.100.88:31080/uaa/login
<html>
<head><title>308 Permanent Redirect</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>308 Permanent Redirect</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.13.12</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I notice ingress-nginx receive the request, shown as below:

```
[root@master8g ingress]# kubectl logs ingress-nginx-6ccc799fbc-7clb6
172.16.100.88 - [172.16.100.88] - - [08/Jun/2018:09:16:01 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 308 188 "-" "curl/7.29.0" 83 0.000 [default-gearbox-rack-api-gateway-5555] - - - - 322eb1a195d940d5aa690d81ba9d0a4b
172.16.100.88 - [172.16.100.88] - - [08/Jun/2018:09:16:15 +0000] "GET /uaa/login HTTP/1.1" 308 188 "-" "curl/7.29.0" 92 0.000 [default-gearbox-rack-api-gateway-5555] - - - - 31dabba6b0e6cbbc899ec1248ffacd92
172.16.100.88 - [172.16.100.88] - - [08/Jun/2018:09:20:39 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 308 188 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36" 383 0.000 [default-gearbox-rack-api-gateway-5555] - - - - a00e1c447b581e46566fbb216134e993
172.16.100.88 - [172.16.100.88] - - [08/Jun/2018:09:20:39 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x02\x00\x01\x00\x01\xFC\x03\x03\x1A\xBB\xB6R\xB3Y\xCF;\x95\xBD[B\xC4\x09\x15\xE8\xE35C6\x82\xB0mN\xE9~p\xC4\x87M\x89H O\xCC4\xB6'\xCC\xAA\xA9\xC5\xB6\xDC\xFE" 400 174 "-" "-" 0 0.001 [] - - - - c914c5f584a1cec087e33a5ebd8b1c8d
172.16.100.88 - [172.16.100.88] - - [08/Jun/2018:09:20:39 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x02\x00\x01\x00\x01\xFC\x03\x03\xD15\xD8&\x9F\x0E\xBB\xFF\xFE\xF0\xD5x\xD17\xF6\x01\xD1\x91\x0E\x1E\x84\x8C\x94(\xBD\xF81\xA0\x80\xB4\xE7q \xB5\x1D\xEEG9\x09g\xBCi\x85BC\xCB\x9Ag\xD9@'\xB6 \x18\x8F\xC8" 400 174 "-" "-" 0 0.002 [] - - - - 8164c246d67cb97331ec5230679e7e6f
172.16.100.88 - [172.16.100.88] - - [08/Jun/2018:09:20:39 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\xAE\x01\x00\x00\xAA\x03\x03U\xC5\x22.\x9Eq\xCD\xDFi\xE0\x0B\x11\x93\xD0L\x9C\xCE\xBA\xD1\xA3\xE6\x124y\xA6\xEA\xB8\x88I\x97\x1F\xB8\x00\x00\x1C\x8A\x8A\xC0+\xC0/\xC0,\xC00\xCC\xA9\xCC\xA8\xC0\x13\xC0\x14\x00\x9C\x00\x9D\x00/\x005\x00" 400 174 "-" "-" 0 0.001 [] - - - - 0556f985d88e3ede2217459ab75ab4f4


ingress_nginx_res.yaml:
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
spec:
  rules:
   - host:
     http:
       paths:
       - path: /
         backend:
           serviceName: gearbox-rack-api-gateway
           servicePort: 5555
```

Comment: replace "ingress-controller-leader-dev" with "ingress-controller-leader-nginx" in your rbac yaml.

Comment: The fails disappear, but service external IP is still pending? any hint?

Comment: since you don't use any cloude platform, the 'loadbalancer' defined in your controller service is not working, and should be deleted. you can define 'type: NodePort" in you service yaml or just define 'hostNetwork: true" in your deployment yaml.

Comment: @Kun Li: Please see my second edition above.

Comment: Try http://gearbox-rack-api-gateway:31826/uaa/login, gearbox-rack-api-gateway should be pointed to the ip of the host

Comment: @user84592 please check my answer to your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/50704947/9524052. I hope it will help you with resolving this issue

Comment: @ArtemGolenyaev Thank you to help me. I have update latest yaml files in this question, I still meet some problem.

Comment: @user84592 what kind of problems do you have, it is hard to understand root cause of the problem only by configs

Comment: @ArtemGolenyaev I got connection refused. I found telnet localhost 31080 does not work, telnet -6 localhost 31080 works. so Port 31080 is binding to IPv6 address. What shall I do to make it listen to IPv4?

Comment: @ArtemGolenyaev Please see second edition.

Comment: @ArtemGolenyaev Would you please see my third edition in the question. I have final issues. My gut feeling told me if there is a magic touch, ingress problem would be resolved.

Comment: @user84592 you are right, Ingress-controller and service for that Ingress-controller should be in the same namespace. And, it is better to place Ingress object with rules in namespace with applications.

Comment: @ArtemGolenyaev It did make a progress. Now nginx seems direct my http to https, pelease see forth edition in the question. How to solve status code 308 issue will help me make ingress working. And backend log could see the request.

Comment: @ArtemGolenyaev after looking https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/668, it means I did not put anything in host session. Now ingress works. I come to next Monday to update this queston, so that others could benefit. Thank you, ArtemGolenyaev, KunLi and XiaoYu.

Comment: @user84592, by default the controller redirects (301) to HTTPS if TLS is enabled for that Ingress. If you want to disable that behaviour, you can use the ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false" annotation.

Answer (score -2):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: gearbox-rack-eureka-server
  labels:
    name: gearbox_rack_eureka_server
spec:
  selector:
    app: gearbox-rack-eureka-server
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 8761
      name: tcp
```

---

name: tcp -> protocol: TCP ?